# R barplot- How to change barplot color depending on column name?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and I'm wondering how to change the color of the bar depending on the column name. When I plot the below, I get a barplot that alternates bars that are green, red, yellow, and blue (repeating) instead of having everything in column A (the first 5 bars) colored green.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,1,4,5),B=c(1,6,3,8,4),C=c(2,1,4,8,9), D=c(4,1,2,4,6))
row.names(df)<-c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5")
print(df)
col.colors <- c(A="green", B="red", C="yellow", D="blue")
barplot(as.vector(as.matrix(df)), names = as.matrix(df), col=col.colors[colnames(df)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you elimiate the matrix shape with `as.vector()`, you'll need to repeat the valuers for each row of data you have. For example

```
barplot(as.vector(as.matrix(df)), names = as.matrix(df), 
  col=rep(col.colors[colnames(df)], each=nrow(df)))
```

[image]